# Why is my timestamp inconsistent?

Tags: grafana

Why is the timestamp in my graph inconsistent? I want a consistent time difference of 10s between each data point, but as you can see in the first 'Time' column, the time difference is random 10s, 20s, 30s etc.
[image]